# Use one class variables in another class

Tags: php, class, oop

How do I can access base class variables in another classes wich are loaded into base class?

Base class example

```
class base {

   public $get;

   public function __get( $name ) {
      require_once $name . '.php';
      $this->name = new $name( $this );
      return $this->name;
   }

   public function __construct( $varfromphplib ) {
     $this->varfromphplib = $varfromphplib;
     $this->get = explode( "/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
   }
}

$class = new base( $varfromphplib );
```

another class example (loaded into base class with __get)

```
class another {
   public function showGet() {
      //there I wanna return base class $this->get;
   }

   public function getLibClass(){
      //there I wanna return $varfromphplib variable with baseclass prefix or not if can
   }
}
//usage in base class
$this->another->showGet( );
```

I don't know how to be able to acces base class variables like $get in "another" class
Hope someone will be able to help me with this.

Comment: When you say "inherited classes" do you know what that means?

Comment: What's the relation between `base` and `inherited`? Does `inherited` extend `base`? If so, your code is wrong. If not, you are incorrectly using terminology which will only hinder you (and us).

Comment: Ok my english is very bad, I will try to edit to help you understand my situation

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php, but I would suggest to read the entire chapter http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score -1):

If one class is inherited from the other (A extends B) you can call variables from the parent class by using $this->variable. Note that this only works if the inheriting class doesn't have an own constructor and doesn't have a variable by the same name.

If any of that keeps you from using $this, you can always call the parent classes variables just like you would call any public variables from unrelated classes.
i.e.: A has protected variable $a and B extends A but has an own variable named $b.

`$objA = new A();
echo "A->a = ".$objA->a;`

Comment: by calling return $this->get in my "another" class and then use print_r( $class->another->showGet() ); shows me nothing, and $varfromphplib is because I use IPBWI and this is only way i know how to load ipbwi into my own class, but this works only on base class not classes wich are loaded into base class. I don't know how to say it right, to let you understand my problem.